# Counting the number of semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I am having some issue understanding how to count the number of semidirect products we can obtain. Take for example $\mathbb{Z}_{7} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_6$. I understand that this would be counting the number of homomorphisms $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{7}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$, but how would I go about counting these homomorphisms, or actually generating the semidirect products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the way you do this is by listing the homomorphisms, then thinking about the result you got.

For instance, note that $\mathbb Z_6$ is generated by a single element $g$ of order $6$. In particular, a homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z_6\rightarrow G$ is determined by $f(g)$ subject to the condition that $f(g)^6=e$. More specifically, since every element in $\mathbb Z_6$ has order diving $6$, for each $\alpha\in \mathbb Z_6$ there is a unique homomorphism $f_{\alpha}:\mathbb Z_6\rightarrow \mathbb Z_6$ with $f_{\alpha}(g)=\alpha$. Explicitly, in additive notation, this is just $f_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha x$. So, there are six homomorphisms.

If you want to actually *write down* the semi-direct products that this yields, recall that the $G\rtimes_{\phi} H$ where $\phi:H\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is basically defined to have $G$ as a normal subgroup on which an element $h\in H$ acts by conjugation as $\phi(h)$. Observing that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_7)$ is just maps of the form $x\mapsto x^c$ for $c\in \{1,\ldots,6\}$ and we have shown that a generator of $\mathbb Z_6$ could be mapped to any such element by some homomorphism $f_c$, we can actually write down a generic presentation for a semidirect product, where $c\in\{1,\ldots,6\}$:
$$\mathbb Z_7\rtimes_{f_c} \mathbb Z_6\cong \langle x,g |x^7=e,g^6=e,gxg^{-1}=x^c\rangle.$$
Then, you can use ad hoc reasoning to figure out which of these six groups are isomorphic.

(Of course, there are some more sophisticated ways to deal with the question of isomorphism, but for this case it's just as easy to classify the six groups by hand.)

Comment: What about this: a homomorphism can be uniquely determined by its image which is going to be $\mathbb{Z}_{6}/ker(\mathbb{Z}_{6})$. Since the kernel is a subgroup it must be of order divisor of the group, meaning it can be 1,2,3, or 6 in this case, meaning there are four semidirect products

Comment: @GTOgod Well, you get the right answer, but your reasoning doesn't work out - first, homomorphisms are not determined by their image (e.g. $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto -x$ are two homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_6\rightarrow \mathbb Z_6$ with the same image). Second, the image of $\phi$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_6/\ker \phi$, but this is a case where we care about the *actual* image (e.g. $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto 2x$ on $\mathbb Z$ have the same kernel, but different images). Also, subgroups are not in general determined by their order, and dividing the order of the group is not sufficient for a...

Comment: ...subgroup of that order to exist. Since $\mathbb Z_6$ is a really nice group, these issues don't cause an error in the result, but better reasoning is necessary. You might try showing that if two maps $\mathbb Z_6\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_7)$ have the same image, they induce isomorphic semi-direct products (this can be done by noting that, if two maps out of $\mathbb Z_6$ have the same image, they are in fact related by composition with an automorphism of $\mathbb Z_6).